# Nuget package missing .target file in build folder

Tags: nuget, target

I have build a nuget package at published it to a nuget.server site. But when I try to use the package form the server the .targets file from build folder is not in the file. But if I use the package from a local folder it works as it should. How do I get it to work ?

If i look in the package in the folder on the server it looks ok.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me if you mean using (referencing and restoring) a package, or building (packing) a package.

If the problem is with packing the nupkg, NuGet requires the props and targets files to have [specific filenames in specific folders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package#including-msbuild-props-and-targets-in-a-package), but if you got it to work at least once, you probably already know that. If this is not the problem with packing, you need to give us more information because not using the correct filename convention is the most common problem and I can't guess what else the problem could be. In particular, if the package is being packed differently on your local machine compared to when it is packed on the server, it means there is something different between how you pack on the two computers, so we need more information about how the build and pack work with your project.

If the problem is with using (restoring) the package, there are a few possibilities. My best guess is that you once had a package without the targets file working correctly, and you restored the package on the server. By design, NuGet packages are immutable which means it's invalid for the contents of a package (same ID and version) to change. This allows NuGet to download the package from a remote feed once, save it in the global package folder (not a cache; they never expire) and the next time NuGet needs to restore the same package (id + version) it uses the one in the global package folder, it does not download again. This means if you once built a bad nupkg and restored it on a machine, then fix the nupkg and kept the same version number, that machine will never get the fixed nupkg. You need to delete it from the global packages folder. I'm not 100% sure, but I think if you have a local file feed and you restore a project that uses `packages.config`, the nupkg does not get saved in the global packages folder, so doesn't have the same problem.  In short, I think the problem is that you changed the nupkg contents once without changing the version number, and one of the machines has the old copy in its global packages folder that it keeps using.

If that's not the problem, the next most likely cause is that the nupkg on the server feed has different contents to the nupkg in the local feed. I've never used `NuGet.Server`, but some nuget respositories (like nuget.org) do not allow overwriting nupkgs. So, if you pushed a nupkg to your server, fixed a problem in your nupkg without changing the version, then tried to push again, the second push might have failed.

In summary, your question doesn't provide enough information for us to help you, but I wrote about the most common issues above. If it doesn't help, you need to provide us with more information. An [example of the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is the best way to give us enough information to help you.